# Java calling array from another class

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am trying to store an `arrayList` of objects to a text file created from the array `ipvalue[]` which is instantiated in another class. My problem is that whenever i try to load the array from the `Mainframe` class to the `Arraystorage` class, it displays the entire array as null outputs. I guess the problem is that the array data is generated within the Mainframe method, and when I call the array from another class it simply takes the array as it is initialized. So my question is how do I how can I access the array after it is assigned value rather then when it is initialized.

```
new String[50] 
mainframe class:



public class Mainframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {
static int ipcounter = 0;
public static String[] ipvalue = new String [50];


/**
 * String a[]Creates new form Mainframe
 */
    public Mainframe() {
         try {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocation(500,250);
        Nettest.main(null);
        Display.setText(Nettest.indicator);
        Arraystorage.main(null);
        Path path = Paths.get("ipcounter.txt");

         File file = new File("ipcounter.txt");


         FileReader in = new FileReader("ipcounter.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

        readline = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()); 
        in.close();
        ipcounter = readline;

         if(ip.tracker.Nettest.status == true){
         ipvalue[ipcounter] = Readipfromurl.inputLine;
       //  crosscheck();

        Writer writer = null;
         writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
         new FileOutputStream("ipcounter.txt"), "utf-8"));
          writer.write(String.valueOf(ipcounter+1));

          writer.close();
         System.out.println(ipvalue[ipcounter]);
          ipcounter++;


arraystorage class:


public class Arraystorage implements Serializable{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws 
 ClassNotFoundException { 

   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i=0; i<50;i++){
  list.add(Mainframe.ipvalue[i]);}
   try {
       PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new 
  FileWriter("data.txt")));
   for( int x = 0; x < list.size(); x++)
 {
 out.println(list.get(x));
 }

   out.close();


   } catch (IOException ex) {

 Logger.getLogger(Arraystorage.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, 
null, ex);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you are not calling `Mainframe()` that fills your array with data. You should do it in the `main` method before you need to use `ipvalue` array. So, just call this method on the `Mainframe` instance:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws  ClassNotFoundException { 

  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Mainframe frame = new Mainframe();
  frame.Mainframe();
  for (int i=0; i<50;i++){
  list.add(Mainframe.ipvalue[i]);
  }
  ... // do the rest
```

In long, please, read at least [Oracle Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for Java basics for naming conventions, code structure and many more

Answer (score 1):

Create a static block initializer:

```
public class Mainframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static int ipcounter = 0;
    public static String[] ipvalue = new String [50];

    static {
        File file = new File("ipcounter.txt");
        FileReader in = new FileReader("ipcounter.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);

        // Fill your ipvalue

        in.close();
    }

    // The rest of your class definition
    public MainFrame() {

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you guys are probably right but i found another solution
in the mainframe class i call the main method of arraystorage 
     Arraystorage.main(null);
after i assign values to the array and it works!